# Is there a create() method in the Manager class of Django?

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

So, I recently started learning Django and found out about the two ways to create obejcts in database using their given API. Now, one of the methods is to use the create() methods that is provided by Manager class as follows :

`joe = Author.objects.create(name="joe")`

Now, objects is the default manager given by Django but I could not find create() method inside the source code. Please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

`create(**kwargs)` methods provided by `QuerySet`. That method allows you to create some object immediately and returning the created object itself. For the detail, you can find the `create()` method on the Django installation directory. Exactly in `python-path/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py`